# msbuild script unable to build specific build config of C++ Builder 2010 project

Tags: msbuild, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I have a project group in C++ Builder 2010. It contains several projects. One of these projects has, besides *Debug* and *Releae*, a *Demo* build configuration that is a *child* of the *Release* one.

The issue I run into is that if I run this from the build script we have, calling the project group file and telling it I want to build using the *Demo* configuration I get an error about *unresolved WinMain*. I get the same error by using a build configuration name that does not exist. So my initial thought was that this had to be due to the fact that the other projects in the project group didn't have a *Demo* configuration. But when I tried running msbuild against the project group file from cmd passing it *Demo* it built just fine.

```
C:\src\foo\AutoBuild> msbuild ..\foo.groupproj /t:build /p:Configuration=Demo
```

The same goes for building the specific project using msbuild from cmd. I have checked that the *Config*/*Configuration* property is carried over through each `<msbuild />` task call and it is.

Hacking the project group (*.groupproj*) file and forcing it to run *Demo* for the project in question when running *Release* also worked.

```
...

<Target Name="Foo:Make">
  <MSBuild Targets="Make" Projects="Foo.cbproj" Properties="Config=Demo"/>
</Target>

...
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

**Update**

Also, by running only the specific project in the main build script when *Demo* is selected it also works fine. Note that the *Release* build has been built by the build script prior to this.

```
<Target Name="Foo:Build">

...

  <MSBuild Condition="$(Configuration)==''" Targets="Make" Projects="..\Server\Bar.groupproj" Properties="Config=Release" />
  <MSBuild Condition="$(Configuration)==''" Targets="Foo" Projects="..\Server\Bar.groupproj" Properties="Config=Demo" />

...

</Target>
```

Comment: What is the build script doing if it isn't calling msbuild like in the example above?

Comment: When it was acting up it was running against the Target **make** and not **foo** for Demo as well. That works when running msbuild from cmd and specifying those settings, but not when running the buildscript.